# Python Yaml parse inf as float

Tags: python, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

In PyYaml or ruamel.yaml I'm wondering if there is a way to handle parsing of specific strings. Specifically, I'd like to be able to parse `"[inf, nan]"` as `[float('inf'), float('nan')]`. I'll also note that I would like `"['inf', 'nan']"` to continue to parse as `['inf', 'nan']`, so it's just the unquoted variant that I'd like to intercept and change the current behavior.

I'm aware that currently I could use `"[.inf, .nan]"` or `"[!!float inf, !!float nan]"`, but I'm curious if I could extend the Loader to allow for the syntax that I expected would have worked (but doesn't).

Perhaps I'm just making a footgun by allowing "nan" and "inf" to be parsed as floats rather than strings - and I'm interested in hearing compelling reasons that I should *not* allow for this type of parsing. But I'm not too woried about the case where other parses would parse my configs incorrectly (but maybe I'm underestimating the pain that will cause in the future). I plan to use this as a one way convineince in parsing arguments on the command line, and I don't expect actual config files to be written like this.

In any case I'd still be interested in how it could be done, even if the conclusion is that it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the confusion that I have seen caused by `Yes`, `On`, `No` and `Off` being
interpreted as boolean values in YAML 1.1, I don't think this is a good idea.

But it is possible to do this both in `ruamel.yaml` and PyYAML, by changing the regex
that recognises floats (i.e. that assigns the implicit tag `tag:yaml.org,2002:float` to the scalar)
and then to make sure the routine constructing a float from a scalar handles these additional
scalars. The three main improvements (with regard to this) in `ruamel.yaml` are that
it has different regexes for YAML 1.1 and YAML 1.2 parsing (the latter being the default,
the former having to be specified either by a directive, or by setting `.version` on the `YAML()` instance);
that the various Resolvers each have a copy of these regexes instead of sharing
one (as in PyYAML, which makes having multiple, differently behaving parsers in one program difficult);
and that regex compilation is delayed until they are actually needed.

Given the differences, the following will only apply to `ruamel.yaml`

You need to create a resolver, and replace its regex recognition for *all* floats,
and then create a constructor that constructs the floats based on the
recognised scalars:

```py
import re, sys
import ruamel.yaml

class NanInfResolver(ruamel.yaml.resolver.VersionedResolver):
    pass

# difference with the regex in resolver.py is the ? after \\.
# as well as recognising N and I as starting chars
# no delayed compile of the regex here
NanInfResolver.add_implicit_resolver(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:float',
    re.compile('''^(?:
     [-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)\\.[0-9_]*(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?(?:[0-9][0-9_]*)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)
    |[-+]?\\.[0-9_]+(?:[eE][-+][0-9]+)?
    |[-+]?\\.?(?:inf|Inf|INF)       
    |\\.?(?:nan|NaN|NAN))$''', re.X),
    list('-+0123456789.niNI')
)

class NanInfConstructor(ruamel.yaml.constructor.RoundTripConstructor):
    def construct_yaml_float(self, node):
        value = self.construct_scalar(node).lower()
        sign = +1
        if value[0] == '-':
            sign = -1
        if value[0] in '+-':
            value_s = value_s[1:]
        if value == 'inf':
            return sign * self.inf_value
        if value == 'nan':
            return self.nan_value
        return super().construct_yaml_float(node)

NanInfConstructor.add_constructor(
    'tag:yaml.org,2002:float', NanInfConstructor.construct_yaml_float
)



yaml_str = """\
[nano, 1.0, .NaN, inf, nan]  # some extra values to test
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.Resolver = NanInfResolver
yaml.Constructor = NanInfConstructor

data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for x in data:
    print(type(x), x)
print()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'str'> nano
<class 'ruamel.yaml.scalarfloat.ScalarFloat'> 1.0
<class 'float'> nan
<class 'float'> inf
<class 'float'> nan

[nano, 1.0, .nan, .inf, .nan] # some extra values to test
```

That `1.0` is loaded as a `ScalarFloat` is necessary to preserve its formatting when
dumping. It is possible to preserve the different ways of writing `.nan`, `.inf`, `nan` and `inf` in a similar way, but you would
have to make a special representer and either extend `ScalarFloat` or make one
or more explicit types that keep the the original scalar string value. Either way you
would lose the possibility to test with `x is float('nan')` which may be a problem
in real programs (which is also the
reason why `ruamel.yaml` doesn't preserve the different forms of null during round-trip).